# Site or app to type in two languages at the same time?

Tags: translation

I am an Anglophone, but with the assistance of online translation and a colleague looking over my shoulder, I am able to make myself understood in Spanish.

I am often writing emails or WhatsApp messages where some of the recipients read English and others read Spanish. My "Spanish" is better than their English, for the Spanish speakers, so I don't want to leave them to translate things themselves. In an email it would look like:

> Hello everyone! 
> *Hola a todas!*
>
> Would it be possible for you to send us a scan, rather than a photo,
> of the document? 
> *¿Le sería posible enviarnos un escaneo, en lugar de una fotografía, del documento?*

Going back-and-forth copying and pasting is incredible tedious. Is there an app or site or extension or something that would allow me to write the message in two languages simultaneously?

Windows 11, happy to use whatever browser works if it's an extension or something.

Comment: I just noticed that post is a "self duplicate" of [Site or app to type in two languages at the same time?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/88863/site-or-app-to-type-in-two-languages-at-the-same-time). Please don't cross-post questions across [se] sites.